# Multiple forms with zedgraphs. Line on one continues when the next starts

Tags: c#, multithreading, visual-studio, zedgraph

Ok, this could be a little tough to explain. I have a method that computes X and Y values that I want to plot. This method is purely backend and runs inside a backgroundworker called from my main GUI thread.

Separate from my main form I have a form that contains only a zedgraph and a ticker. I use the combination to display the rolling X,Y spit out from my background thread. This works fine, everything goes great here.

When I click a button on my main GUI the backgroundworker is closed, and zedgraph stops updating. Here's where my problem starts

When I click the stop button the graph needs to stay up. It does this just fine... iff it's the very first time it was run. On all future graphs this happens: (Top image is the first graph, second image is the second graph.)

[image: graph wit connected first and last point]

The first graph keeps updating when it isn't supposed to. How do I keep this from happening? Is there a way to "shut down" the first zedgraph and keep it from listening for new data?

Below is my zedgraph code, I'm pretty sure the problem is in here somewhere and not my main GUI code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using ZedGraph;

namespace RTHERM
{
    public partial class Readout : Form
    {
        // Starting time in milliseconds
        public static float Time_old = 0.0f;
        public static float Tsurf_old;
        public static float Tmidr_old;
        public static float Tcent_old;
        public static float Tenvi_old;

        //  Every "redrawInterval" secods plot a new point (if one is available)
        public static int redrawInterval;
        public int plotRange = 15;      //   Plot will span "plotRange" minutes


        int tickStart = 0;

        public Readout()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //timer1.Equals(0);
            GUI gui = new GUI();
            GraphPane graph = zedGraph.GraphPane;
            graph.Title.Text = GUI.plotTitle;
            graph.XAxis.Title.Text = "Time [min]";
            graph.YAxis.Title.Text = "Temperature [F]";

            graph.Legend.Position = ZedGraph.LegendPos.BottomCenter;
            // Save 1200 points.  At 50 ms sample rate, this is one minute
            // The RollingPointPairList is an efficient storage class that always
            // keeps a rolling set of point data without needing to shift any data values
            RollingPointPairList surfList = new RollingPointPairList(1200);
            //surfList.Clear();
            RollingPointPairList midrList = new RollingPointPairList(1200);
            //midrList.Clear();
            RollingPointPairList centList = new RollingPointPairList(1200);
            //centList.Clear();
            RollingPointPairList furnList = new RollingPointPairList(1200);
            //furnList.Clear();
            // Initially, a curve is added with no data points (list is empty)
            // Color is blue, and there will be no symbols
            LineItem surf = graph.AddCurve("Surface", surfList, Color.DarkBlue, SymbolType.None);
            LineItem midr = graph.AddCurve("Mid-Radius", midrList, Color.DarkOliveGreen, SymbolType.None);
            LineItem cent = graph.AddCurve("Center", centList, Color.DarkOrange, SymbolType.None);
            LineItem furn = graph.AddCurve("Ambient", furnList, Color.Red, SymbolType.None);
            surf.Line.Width = 2;
            midr.Line.Width = 2;
            cent.Line.Width = 2;
            furn.Line.Width = 2;

            // Check for new data points
            timer1.Interval = redrawInterval;
            timer1.Enabled = true;
            //timer1.Start();

            // Just manually control the X axis range so it scrolls continuously
            // instead of discrete step-sized jumps
            graph.XAxis.Scale.Min = 0;
            graph.XAxis.Scale.Max = plotRange;
            graph.XAxis.Scale.MinorStep = 1;
            graph.XAxis.Scale.MajorStep = 5;

            // Scale the axes
            zedGraph.AxisChange();

            // Save the beginning time for reference
            tickStart = Environment.TickCount;
        }

        //  USING A TIMER OBJECT TO UPDATE EVERY FEW MILISECONDS
        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Only redraw if we have new information
            if (Transfer.TTIME != Time_old)
            {
                GraphPane graph = this.zedGraph.GraphPane;
                // Make sure that the curvelist has at least one curve
                if (zedGraph.GraphPane.CurveList.Count <= 0)
                    return;

                // Grab the three lineitems
                LineItem surf = this.zedGraph.GraphPane.CurveList[0] as LineItem;
                LineItem midr = this.zedGraph.GraphPane.CurveList[1] as LineItem;
                LineItem cent = this.zedGraph.GraphPane.CurveList[2] as LineItem;
                LineItem furn = this.zedGraph.GraphPane.CurveList[3] as LineItem;

                if (surf == null)
                    return;

                // Get the PointPairList
                IPointListEdit surfList = surf.Points as IPointListEdit;
                IPointListEdit midrList = midr.Points as IPointListEdit;
                IPointListEdit centList = cent.Points as IPointListEdit;
                IPointListEdit enviList = furn.Points as IPointListEdit;

                // If these are null, it means the reference at .Points does not
                // support IPointListEdit, so we won't be able to modify it
                if (surfList == null || midrList == null || centList == null || enviList == null)
                    return;

                // Time is measured in seconds
                double time = (Environment.TickCount - tickStart) / 1000.0;

                // ADDING THE NEW DATA POINTS
                // format is List.Add(X,Y)  Finally something that makes sense!
                surfList.Add(Transfer.TTIME, Transfer.TSURF);
                midrList.Add(Transfer.TTIME, Transfer.TMIDR);
                centList.Add(Transfer.TTIME, Transfer.TCENT);
                enviList.Add(Transfer.TTIME, Transfer.TENVI);

                // Keep the X scale at a rolling 10 minute interval, with one
                // major step between the max X value and the end of the axis
                if (GUI.isRunning)
                {
                    Scale xScale = zedGraph.GraphPane.XAxis.Scale;
                    if (Transfer.TTIME > xScale.Max - xScale.MajorStep)
                    {
                        xScale.Max = Transfer.TTIME + xScale.MajorStep;
                        xScale.Min = xScale.Max - plotRange;
                    }
                }
                // Make sure the Y axis is rescaled to accommodate actual data
                zedGraph.AxisChange();
                // Force a redraw
                zedGraph.Invalidate();
            }
            else return;
        }

        public void reset()
        {
            Time_old = 0.0f;
            Tsurf_old = 0.0f;
            Tmidr_old = 0.0f;
            Tcent_old = 0.0f;
            Tenvi_old = 0.0f;
        }
        private void Form1_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (GUI.isRunning)
            {
                SetSize();
            }
        }

        // Set the size and location of the ZedGraphControl
        private void SetSize()
        {
            // Control is always 10 pixels inset from the client rectangle of the form
            Rectangle formRect = this.ClientRectangle;
            formRect.Inflate(-10, -10);

            if (zedGraph.Size != formRect.Size)
            {
                zedGraph.Location = formRect.Location;
                zedGraph.Size = formRect.Size;
            }
        }

        private void saveGraph_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            GUI.Pause();
            zedGraph.DoPrint();
            //SaveFileDialog saveDialog = new SaveFileDialog();
            //saveDialog.ShowDialog();
        }

        private void savePlotDialog_FileOk(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
        {
            // Get file name.
            string name = savePlotDialog.FileName;
            zedGraph.MasterPane.GetImage().Save(name);
            GUI.Resume();
        }

        private bool zedGraphControl1_MouseMoveEvent(ZedGraphControl sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            // Save the mouse location
            PointF mousePt = new PointF(e.X, e.Y);

            // Find the Chart rect that contains the current mouse location
            GraphPane pane = sender.MasterPane.FindChartRect(mousePt);

            // If pane is non-null, we have a valid location.  Otherwise, the mouse is not
            // within any chart rect.
            if (pane != null)
            {
                double x, y;
                // Convert the mouse location to X, and Y scale values
                pane.ReverseTransform(mousePt, out x, out y);
                // Format the status label text
                toolStripStatusXY.Text = "(" + x.ToString("f2") + ", " + y.ToString("f2") + ")";
            }
            else
                // If there is no valid data, then clear the status label text
                toolStripStatusXY.Text = string.Empty;

            // Return false to indicate we have not processed the MouseMoveEvent
            // ZedGraphControl should still go ahead and handle it
            return false;
        }

        private void Readout_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void Readout_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            //e.Cancel = true;
            //WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So how are you stopping it, you stop the timer? Your code doesn't show that.

Answer (score 0):

The last point is connected to the first point in the graph. I suspect, because all your `RollingPointPairList` contains the data multiple times. Verify this using a breakpoint in your `timer1_Tick`function.

On `private void Form1_Load` you will add the complete list to the `LineItem`.

```
graph.CurveList.Clear();
LineItem surf = graph.AddCurve("Surface", surfList, Color.DarkBlue, SymbolType.None);
LineItem midr = graph.AddCurve("Mid-Radius", midrList, Color.DarkOliveGreen, SymbolType.None);
LineItem cent = graph.AddCurve("Center", centList, Color.DarkOrange, SymbolType.None);
LineItem furn = graph.AddCurve("Ambient", furnList, Color.Red, SymbolType.None);
```