# Real-time Zedgraph does not respond

Tags: c#, user-interface, focus, real-time, zedgraph

My real-time does not respond any more when I change focus from it to another program. I.e. it gets stuck.

Could you please suggest me a possible reason and/or solution for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your **GUI thread (background) isn't beeing processed**, when it looses focus, your Zedgraph isn't updated. If you move a window over the ZedGraph, it isn't replotted. Instead you will see the focused window. That's my first guess. Since I don't know your programming language and code, I will just show the principle in C#.

A [timer](http://www.dotnetperls.com/timer) or a new data event calls a function `RealTimeGraph`. The clue is that an extra thread besides the GUI thread calls `RealTimeGraph`. The [`Systems.Timers.Timer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.timers.timer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class already does that for you. Which Timer or BackgroundWorker to use depends on your application.

```
System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(RealTimeGraph)

Public void RealTimeGraph(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (this.InvokeRequired)
  {
    PeriodicUpdateHandler update = new PeriodicUpdateHandler(this.RealTimeGraph);
    this.BeginInvoke(periodic_update,sender, e);
  }
  else
  {
    Update();                          // check if new data for ZedGraph is available
    ZedGraph.GraphPane.AxisChange();   // optional, if ZedGraphAxis has to be recomputed
    ZedGraph.control.Invalidate();     // optional
    ZedGraph.control.Refresh();        // now the update is visible
  }
}
```

Additionaly it might be handy to call `RealTimeGraph`, if you focus your application again. Just add a new focus event handler.

```
 this.Enter += new System.EventHandler(this.RealTimeGraph);
```

I hoped to show you the advantages of this concept.

- Verbose [ZedGraph with timer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18037921/multiple-forms-with-zedgraphs-line-on-one-continues-when-the-next-starts/18130404#18130404)
- General handy [examples on codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5431/A-flexible-charting-library-for-NET)